# While making a grid based prize founding game how do i conditionalize the actionPerformed?

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

class ButtonGrid implements ActionListener {
    int numOfGuesses = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
                int prize = (int) (Math.random() * 25);

                int sz = 5;
                Container content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(sz, 0, 2, 2));
                for (int f = 0; f < sz * sz; f++) {
                    JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(f + 1));

                    content.add(button);

                }
                gui.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                Container info = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 5));
                info.add(new JLabel("Guess:"));
                info.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(numOfGuesses)));
                gui.add(info, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                gui.add(new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(){

        }else{
            numOfGuesses++;
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to make a find the prize type game on a 5x5 gird. On the top layer there will be a guess counter. How do i check if the prize integer is equal to the text the button holds and complete the if statement accordingly ?